# Finding Maximum and Mininum of a general cubic

Tags: calculus

A cubic function is a polynomial of degree; that is, it has the form $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

Show that a cubic function can have two, one, or no critical points. Give examples and sketches to illustrate the three possibilities.
How many local extreme values can a cubic function have?
I have tried to differentiate this and got $3ax^2+2bx+c$, but don’t know where to go from here. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

A cubic function is a polynomial of degree three, which means it can be written in the form $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$. To find the critical numbers of a cubic function, we need to find the values of $x$ that make the derivative of the function equal to zero or undefined.

To find the derivative of a cubic function, we can use the power rule for derivatives. This states that the derivative of a term $ax^n$ is $nax^{n-1}$. Therefore, the derivative of $f(x)$ is

$$\begin{aligned} f'(x) &= 3ax^2 + 2bx + c \ &= (3a)x^2 + (2b)x + c \end{aligned}$$

To find the critical numbers of the function, we need to find the values of $x$ that make the derivative equal to zero or undefined. This means we need to solve the equation $3ax^2 + 2bx + c = 0$. This is a quadratic equation, which means it can have two, one, or no solutions (or roots) depending on the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Comment: Moreover, the answer you have given an hour ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4591589/305862) is wrong. Please refrain to write an answer if it is useless or, worse, if it is false.

Comment: Sorry but your answer oesn't bring anything new when you compare it with the question : it should be a comment.